# Javascript firing function twice and 1 of 4 functions not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

I'm creating a calculator in JavaScript.  It is working, except for the `add()` function (sub, mult, and div work fine) and when I press "=" it sends the answer twice in back to back pop-ups.

Add returns the value as if both x and y were strings, i.e. 7+8 = 78.  How can I get it to calculate add, and to send the answer just once?

**calculator.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Calculator</title></head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calc.css"/>
<body>

<p>
    <label for="x">First Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="x" id="x" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="y">Second Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="y" id="y" />
</p>

<p>
    <input type=radio name="Operation" value=Add id="0" /> <label for="0">Add</label>
    <input type=radio name="Operation" value=Sub id="1" /> <label for="1">Sub</label>
    <input type=radio name="Operation" value=Mult id="2" /> <label for="2">Mult</label>
    <input type=radio name="Operation" value=Div id="3" /> <label for="3">Div</label>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="button" value="=" id="equals"/>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="calculator2.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**calculator2.js**

```
var x;
var y;
var sign;
var answer;
var equals = document.getElementById("equals");

document.getElementById("0").addEventListener("click", getSign, false);
document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("click", getSign, false);
document.getElementById("2").addEventListener("click", getSign, false);
document.getElementById("3").addEventListener("click", getSign, false);
document.getElementById("equals").addEventListener("click", Calculator, false);

equals.onclick = function(){
    Calculator();
}

function getSign(event) {
    sign = event.target.id;
}

function add(){
    answer = x+y;
}

function sub(){
    answer = x-y;
}

function mult(){
    answer = x*y;
}

function div(){
    if(y==0){
        alert("Cannot divide by zero");
        return;
    }
    else{
        answer = x/y
    }
}

function Calculator(){
    x = document.getElementById("x").value;
    y = document.getElementById("y").value;


    if (sign == 0){
        add();
    }
    else if (sign == 1){
        sub();
    }
    else if (sign == 2){
        mult();
    }
    else {
        div();
    }

    alert(answer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your calculator is expected to work with numbers you should cast strings (you get from input field) to number type:

```
x = Number(document.getElementById("x").value);
y = Number(document.getElementById("y").value);
```

Of course you could also change `add` function

```
function add() {
    answer = Number(x) + Number(y);
}
```

but this is more like workaround. Arithmetic operations should be done on numbers in first place.

Answer (score 2):

### Why the `add()` function won't work?

The `value` of the the input elements has a `String` type. Using the `+` operator on them will add them as string only. To make it work as you intend, you cast those strings to `Numbers` via the `Number` method.

```
var myString = "1";
var castingToNumber = Number(myString);
console.log(myString, castingToNumber); //logs "1" and 1 (notice the quotes)
```

The reason why this doesn't happen with the `-` operator is that strings can't be subtracted, and thus Javascript automatically parses those strings to `Numbers` and then operates on them. This should NOT be relied upon.

### Two Alerts?

As other answers point out, you have two event listeners. It is recommended that you remove the second event listener, and keep the one defined via `addEventListener`. This allows you to add more event listeners later, without losing the original ones.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 event handlers attached to the clik event of '='(equals) button .Removing event handler one will give  you only one alert with answer

```
document.getElementById("equals").addEventListener("click", Calculator, false);

equals.onclick = function(){
    Calculator();
}
```

From Calculator.js remove

```
equals.onclick = function(){
        Calculator();
    }
```

Also in  function add multiply the value with * 1 to consider the input as number's

```
function add(){
    answer = (x*1)+(y*1);
}
```

This will give you correct sum

Working Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Midhun52/sskatgta/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are defining 2 event handlers, so this is why code Calculator is called twice.

```
document.getElementById("equals").addEventListener("click", Calculator, false);

equals.onclick = function(){
    Calculator();
}
```